# How to make sure all sql queries run without error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three different tables with one column on Auto Increment. When I run a signup PHP script it writes data to all three tables and the information is related to each other. However if I get an error on one of the scripts, it saves data on two of the tables with e.g ID = 4, while the third table still has data of ID = 3. The following are my questions:

1. How can I make sure all the SQL queries run and if one of them fails, it doesn't run at all and mess up my ID's?
2. How to make sure the information is not stored multiple times if the page which has the code to save the data is refreshed and thus, runs more than once?

Comment: 1. Use `TRANSACTION`s. 2. Make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: Test your code before putting into production.

Comment: Do share your code while asking such type of questions, then it is much easier to modify the code instead of writing/defining everything from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is a sequential group of database manipulation operations, which is performed as if it were one single work unit. In other words, a transaction will never be complete unless each individual operation within the group is successful. If any operation within the transaction fails, the entire transaction will fail.

Practically, you will club many SQL queries into a group and you will execute all of them together as part of a transaction.

Read this tutorial about [**MySQL transaction**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you checkout `TRANSACTIONS` in sql. Transactions can run multiple sql queries, with the condition that if one of the queries fail the whole transaction fails and therefore no data is saved in the database.